# I don't understand the SpriteAccessor class (Universal Tween Engine)

Tags: java, libgdx, tween

Just watched Dermetfan's 4th LibGDX video where he uses the Universal Tween Engine to tween the splash screen. And I don't fully understand the SpriteAccessor class. And I don't want to use a bunch of code I don't understand:

```
public static final int ALPHA = 0;

public int getValues(Sprite target, int tweenType, float[] returnValues) {

    switch(tweenType){
    case ALPHA:
        returnValues[0] = target.getColor().a;
        return 1;
    default: assert false; return -1;
    }
}

public void setValues(Sprite target, int tweenType, float[] newValues) {
    switch(tweenType){
    case ALPHA: 
        target.setColor(target.getColor().r, target.getColor().g, target.getColor().b, newValues[0]);
        break;
    default: assert false; 
    }
}
```

Can someone explain this class for me? Where are these methods used? How do they really work?

Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PqwxYVlivA&list=PLXY8okVWvwZ0JOwHiH1TntAdq-UDPnC2L&index=4

Comment: Can you post relevant snippets from a transcript of the video? A question should be answerable without having to go off-site to get question resources.

Comment: This code is invoked from TweenManager. It tells what happens on update of tween manager. And what happens to interpolated values and on which class it should be applied. In this case it tells how to animate Sprite object.

Comment: Read the documentation: http://www.aurelienribon.com/universal-tween-engine/javadoc/aurelienribon/tweenengine/TweenAccessor.html

Answer (score 0):

When yo call yourTweenManagerVariable.update(deltaTime) use the functions to get and set de values, in this case for the alpha of the sprite.

In the call to
Tween.to(spriteVariable, YourTweenType, tweenDuration)
        .target(alphaTargetValue)
        .ease(TweenEquations
                .easeOutBounce // the ease equation
                )
        .start(yourTweenManagerVariable);

you link spriteVariable with yourTweenManagerVariable, so in the functions you post, Sprite target is spriteVariable.

This is how all is integrated.

Here is an exxample i used and works!

```
public class Piece {
class PieceTween implements TweenAccessor<Piece> {

    public static final int FALLING     = 1;

    @Override
    public int getValues(Piece piece, int type, float[] values) {
        switch (type) {
        case FALLING:
            values[0] = piece.getPosition().y;
            return 1;
        };
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValues(Piece piece, int type, float[] values) {
        switch (type) {
        case FALLING:
            piece.getPosition().y = values[0];
            break;
        };          
    }
};

    // Piece variables
    private TweenManager tweenManager = new TweenManager();

    public Piece() {
        if (Tween.getRegisteredAccessor(Piece.class) == null) {
            Tween.registerAccessor(Piece.class, new PieceTween());
        }
    }

    public void drop(Vector2 position) {
        state = State.Falling;

        Tween.to(this, PieceTween.FALLING, duration)
        .target(position.y)
        .ease(TweenEquations
                .easeOutBounce
                )
        .start(tweenManager);
    }

    public void update(float dt) {
        switch (state) {
        case Falling:
            tweenManager.update(dt);
            if (tweenManager.getRunningTweensCount()==0) {
                state = State.Idle;
            }
            break;
        };
    }       
};
```